# From db to css file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a small set of css items in a db table that I need to turn into a css file to be included on a page. How can I do this in Rails3?

Is there a way I can call this directly from a stylesheet_link tag? Do I need to go through some ruby to open a file and output it in some directory first? Do I do this in a controller?

The css is actually its own model associated to the item using the css.

I do not know and looking for a solution found little yet, so asking here.

EDIT:

Simple when looked at, I was looking toward a sass or less solution and may still, but this is a simple start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create a Controller that retrieves the data from the database that uses a View to render the data to a Cascading Style Sheet.

You could then reference the given URL whenever you need to use the resulting stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way that I have found http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/10/18/simpler-than-dirt-restful-dynamic-css